# Rails Validations - Reverse of Confirmation Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to be sure, two attributes don't have the same value with a validation in my Rails4 application. I know about **confirmation** validation but I need exactly the opposite of that.

Does Rails have this kind of validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom validation I think:

```
validate :check_attribute1_and_attribute2

def check_attribute1_and_attribute2
  if attribute_1 == attribute_2
    errors.add( :column_2, ' Value 2 cannot be similar to Value 1!')
  end
end
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need and wanted a simple solution. I thought this worked out pretty well in the end.

`validates :applicant_id, exclusion: {
    in: -> (reference_request) { [reference_request.reference_id] },
    message: 'cannot also be a reference'
  }`